# Understand Request HTTP Cache-Control

Tags: http, http-headers, browser-cache, cache-control

I know the mechanism of `Cache-Control: no-cache` in **server response** HTTP header, but I want to know **in what circumstance that a browser will send a request with `Cache-Control: no-cache` to server**? I have only see Chrome sent a request with `Cache-Control: max-age=0`.

And **Is there a way that forces browser to send `Cache-Control: no-cache` in every request header?** Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks, I have modified my question, since I still can't figure out how to  force browser to send `Cache-Control: no-cache`.